# Inherit from a class that has the copy constructor deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, compiler-bug, g++4.8

I have class `base` which only contains private default constructor and public deleted copy constructor, and nothing else.

```
class base {
private:
    base() = default;

public:
    base(const base&) = delete;
};
```

If I try to inherit from `base` and create an instance of class `derived` as below, g++ 4.8.2 doesn't compile my code but VC++ 2013 does.

```
class derived : public base {
private:
    derived() = default;
};

derived x;
```

So, is it a bug in g++ or VC++ 2013 just ignored something?

Here's the complete code...

```
class base {
private:
    base() = default;

public:
    base(const base&) = delete;
};

class derived : public base {
private:
    derived() = default;
};

derived x;

int main() { 
}
```

... and g++ error message.

```
main.cpp:12:5: error: 'constexpr derived::derived()' is private
     derived() = default;
     ^
main.cpp:15:9: error: within this context
 derived x;
         ^
main.cpp: In constructor 'constexpr derived::derived()':
main.cpp:3:5: error: 'constexpr base::base()' is private
     base() = default;
     ^
main.cpp:12:5: error: within this context
     derived() = default;
     ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:15:9: note: synthesized method 'constexpr derived::derived()' first required here
 derived x;
         ^
```

Comment: I would argue it's a bug in VS2013. The constructor is private and therefore you can't create an instance of the class.

Comment: But if class derived doesn't inherit from class base, g++ will let it compile. Maybe default constructor marked default is just like implicitly declared default constructor.

Comment: @so61pi The fact that g++ will not diagnose that case is [GCC bug 56429](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56429).

Comment: @Casey Oh thank god, my idea about Explicitly private constructor and Implicitly-declared default constructor was wrong :D .

Comment: But for now, like g++, VC++ 2013 also ignores Explicitly default private constructor.

Comment: Just tested, Clang 3.4 doesn't have this compiler-bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misreading the error, it is telling you that the default constructor for `derived` is not accessible (is `private`) so that you cannot use that to create an object of that type. Now making it `public` at the `derived` level won't help, since the `base` constructor is also `private` and thus cannot be used within the constructor of `derived`.

Why do you want those constructors to be `private`?

Comment: I just tested some C++11 features using VC++ 2013 & g++ :D .